# Color in LaTeX when I want everything to be in black

Tags: color

I would like to have everything in black, but my equations and references are mentioned always in different color, green and red. How can I change it?

Comment: don't use the colorlinks option of hyperref.

Comment: Or, load the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package with the options `colorlinks` *and* `allcolors=black`: `\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=black]{hyperref}`.

Comment: It is better, if you provide the `MWE`...